# How to change marker icons on all plots on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to have a map that changes all marker icons (within certain category) when selecting a radio button.

For example, have a radio button list with years and when selecting a year changes the marker for each city in said categories.

[image: example]

I have looked for examples either with Google Maps API alone, or Google Fusion Tables or any of the javascript plugins that handle Google Maps api but so far I couldn't find any.

Answer (score -1):

Creating maker

```
Paris = new google.maps.Marker({...})
```

In selecting event

```
Paris.setIcon()
```

Comment: Ah, and this can be triggered after the map is set-up? I thought adding markers like this happens only once, when the map is rendered. 

Thanks, I'll try and report back.

Comment: also, I need to change a lot of markers at once, selected by an extra field, one by one would be an overkill, after reading your answer, I have edited the question.